# My yorkie is dirtying the house. What should I do?

Tags: cats, dogs, behavior, training, biting

My Yorkie is 4 months old, and she is a female. What my Yorkie does is eat the cat food, plays in her litter box, she goes in the trash can, and lastly, what I regret the most was when I hit her for the first time.

I usually give her a time out in her cage for 20 mins when she does something wrong but she crossed the line on this one. She push down my plasma screen tv when I was at work. I grabbed a sandal and just whacked her butt very hard that she started shaking under the bed and didn't come out like for 2 hours. I regret it but man I try to be patient with her but nothing work even when I trained her for it.

What should I do so she don't become too destructive?

Comment: she is a puppy. Puppies are destructive. Particularly if left alone and left alone inside a house. Hitting the dog hours after something has happened will only make the dog frightened of you. She has no clue why you were hitting her. Hitting a 4 month old yorkie pup is not ok.

Comment: Also, trash-surfing is extremely difficult to break, look into getting a trashcan with a lid that you can lock and unlock if you are home or not.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so first thing - the cage shouldn't be used as a punishment cell.  Cages should be a place of safety and comfort for a dog.  If you use one as a punishment, then you're taking that comfort away.

And yes, she's a puppy so you should be treating her as such.  For the first few months of his life, our puppy stayed in the kitchen for the main part.  There's nothing around that he can trash in there (at least that we didn't care so much about).  All trips into the rest of the house are supervised and even at 7 months, we don't let him loose on his own.

I'd advise you to get some stair gates (same as you'd use for children) and fence off a room for the puppy she that she feels safe (and it's "her" territory) and its up to you to supervise her travels around the rest of the house.

Obviously, where you feed the cat should be in a separate location to where the puppy lives and you need to move the cat food away when the puppy is around.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of destruction that is happening is beyond what is tolerable. I would recommend kenneling your puppy during the day. As your dog is still a puppy and cannot hold it for an entire workday, either drop by to let it out, have a neighbor come, or hire a dog sitter or dog walker with services like Wag . A dog walker will let your dog go potty, and also get the puppy a walk to let out all of that energy.

If you do not want to kennel your dog all day, take the same approach but with a larger, but still small area. Confine the dog to that area, such as using baby gates, and provide plenty of things to play with to keep the dog busy. 10-12 toys at least, and try to rotate out older toys. For example, you can put all of the dog's food in a toy that they have to roll around or figure out, thus tiring as they eat.